# canvas api draw a line error. (trying to draw a cube)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a "cube" on a canvas plane, using vector co-ordinates, i can draw the 2 squares but connecting them with the 4 lines inside the translate function doesn't seem to work for reasons i can't fathom. any suggestions or help appreciated. here's a js bin http://jsbin.com/rozelenocu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
function Vector(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Vector.prototype.plot = function(other){
    return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
}

var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");



function cube(pos, size, z){
    var s1 = square(pos, size);
    var s2 = square(pos + z, size);
    translate(s1, s2);
}

function square(pos, size){

    var shape = [];

    shape.push(new Vector(pos + size, pos));
    shape.push(new Vector(pos + size, pos + size));
    shape.push(new Vector(pos, pos + size));
    shape.push(new Vector(pos, pos));


    ctx.beginPath();
    var line = 0;

    ctx.moveTo(pos, pos);
    while(line < shape.length) {
        ctx.lineTo(shape[line].x, shape[line].y);
        console.log(shape[line].x);
        line++;
    }
    ctx.stroke();

    return shape;
}

function translate(arr1, arr2) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    arr1.forEach(function(_, i){
        console.log(i);
        ctx.moveTo(arr1[i].x, arr1[i].y);
        ctx.lineTo(arr2[i].x, arr2[i].y);
    });
    ctx.closePath();
}

cube(50, 20, 10);
```

Comment: note:  the bug or buggy logic is inside the translate function(or should be).

Answer (score 0):

it was ctx.closepath that caused the issue. i changed it to ctx.stroke()